# 'Is also on the works' or 'is also in the works', which is correct?

Tags: word-usage

An android version of the app is also on the works.

or

An android version of the app is also in the works.

Which is correct?

Comment: Check [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+works) and then see if this reference recognises 'on the works' as an idiom. Of course, you'll find plenty of examples of 'on the works' on a Google search, mostly non-germane ones such as 'An essay on the works of Byron'; 'Don't rely on the works of the flesh'.

Comment: **"In the works"** means that it is in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct usage is 'in the works'. It is in your work schedule.

A similar one (but perhaps unconnected) is 'spanner in the works', which is to throw a tool into the engine of a machine to stop it working.

More info:
http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/292200.html

Comment: I'd imagine it didn't come from spanner in the works, since that has a different meaning, and the metaphor works differently.

Comment: You're right I'd say. Have edited. :)